# Cannot serialize error type: [ERROR : <LOOP IN SUPERTYPES>]

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, kotlin

I'm getting this error when compiling my project in Android Studio and Bitrise:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot serialize error type: [ERROR : <LOOP IN SUPERTYPES>]
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.SerializerExtension.serializeErrorType(SerializerExtension.kt:72)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.DescriptorSerializer.type$serialization(DescriptorSerializer.kt:485)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.DescriptorSerializer.typeArgument(DescriptorSerializer.kt:588)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.DescriptorSerializer.fillFromPossiblyInnerType(DescriptorSerializer.kt:556)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.DescriptorSerializer.type$serialization(DescriptorSerializer.kt:514)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.DescriptorSerializer.type$serialization(DescriptorSerializer.kt:492)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.DescriptorSerializer.typeParameter(DescriptorSerializer.kt:472)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.DescriptorSerializer.classProto(DescriptorSerializer.kt:78)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.JavaClassesTrackerImplKt.convertToProto(JavaClassesTrackerImpl.kt:98)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.JavaClassesTrackerImpl$onCompletedAnalysis$2.invoke(JavaClassesTrackerImpl.kt:78)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.JavaClassesTrackerImpl$onCompletedAnalysis$2.invoke(JavaClassesTrackerImpl.kt:45)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.PerformanceCounter.time(PerformanceCounter.kt:91)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.JavaClassesTrackerImpl.onCompletedAnalysis(JavaClassesTrackerImpl.kt:77)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:113)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:84)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:374)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:64)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:101)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:365)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:130)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:161)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:63)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:107)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:51)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:463)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:98)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:228)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.access$compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:38)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner$compile$2.invoke(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:90)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:102)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:538)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:98)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:418)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:98)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:920)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:98)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:950)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:919)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:417)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:835)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Currently, I'm using Kotlin version `1.2.41`.

As a workaround I disabled incremental build in gradle.properties with this line: `kotlin.incremental=false`.

Did anyone have that issue? I'm just wondering what is causing it.

Comment: Please report such bugs to our issue tracker: https://kotl.in/issue

Comment: Thanks @AndreyBreslav, I haven't looked into Kotlin issue tracker before posting this question but I see that this problem is already reported here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-23580